# Pythonic way to update a single element of a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Say I have a function call `f(m1)` where `m1` is a numpy matrix. Now, I would like to call `f` on a matrix which is almost identical to `m1`:

```
m2 = m1.copy()
m2[ 2, 7 ] = 43 # or m2[ 2, 7 ] += 43
f(m2)
```

Is there an elegant `f( ... )` one-liner to do that?

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it. However, if your code is organized in a way such that you can generate both `m1` and `m2` in same time, there might be a more elegant and efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, every assignment is a statement and not an expression so you cannot do -

```
f(m2[2,7] = 43)
```

or

`if  (a = 1+2)`

I believe you can do

```
f( modify_matrix(m1) )
```

and define a separate method for modifying m1 matrix.

```
def modify_matrix(m1):
     m1[2,7] = 2
     return m1
```

But above options are more complex if all you need to do is just add one more line of modifying the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For pedagogy's sake, here is a functional way to do it.  `np.where` actually does exactly what you want, but the tricky part is that it accepts a boolean condition, not an index:

```
f(np.where(condition, 43, m1))
```

which sends `43` to `f` wherever `condition` is met, elsewhere it just sends `m1`, so this would likely be simpler if we knew your criteria for choosing the element to change.  As such, the trickiest part is creating the boolean array, which is a bit wasteful anyway.

```
np.where(np.all(np.indices(m1.shape) == np.array([2, 7])[:, None, None], 0), 43, m1)
```

or equivalently:

```
np.where(np.all(np.rollaxis(np.indices(m1.shape),0,3) == np.array([2, 7]), -1), 43, m1)
```

I could have sworn there was an equivalent function that took an index instead of a mask, but unfortunately it seems the similar functions (`np.put`, e.g.) that take indices modify the array in place, instead of returning a new one functionally.  `np.choose` would also work but has the same issues of creating a "choice" array (as opposed to a condition mask array).

In action:

```
In [66]: m1 = np.zeros((4, 9))

In [67]: np.where(np.all(np.indices(m1.shape) == np.array([2, 7])[:,None, None], 0), 43, m1)
Out[67]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  43.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])

In [68]: np.where(np.all(np.rollaxis(np.indices(m1.shape),0,3) == np.array([2, 7]), -1), 43, m1)
Out[68]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  43.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```